# Checking if a word is an isogram

Tags: python, function, tdd

I wrote a program to check if a word is an isogram but after passing the test cases, it says "Your solution failed to pass all the tests"

below is the test cases:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IsogramTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_checks_for_isograms(self):
    word = 'abolishment'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, True),
       msg="Isogram word, '{}' not detected correctly".format(word)
    )

  def test_returns_false_for_nonisograms(self):
    word = 'alphabet'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, False),
      msg="Non isogram word, '{}' falsely detected".format(word)
    )

  def test_it_only_accepts_strings(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      is_isogram(2)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument should be a string',
        context.exception.message,
        'String inputs allowed only'
      )
```

and also below is my code for the tests. it passed the tests but failed some hidden tests:

```
def is_isogram(word):
if type(word) == str or len(word) != 0:
    if not word:
        return (word, False)
    word = word.lower()
    return (word, len(set(word)) == len(word))
else:
    raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
```

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: it is in python language

Comment: find my answer[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924869/check-python-function-determine-isogram-from-codewars/43181468#43181468) Up vote if this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question relates to something i have been working on, i would like to share my findings, so that anyone who is looking for the clear solution of this question uses it.

```
def is_isogram(word):

  word = word.lower()

  try:

      if len(word) > 0:

          for letter in word:

              if word.count(letter) > 1:

                  return (word, False)

          return (word, True)

      else:
          return ('argument', False)

  except TypeError as e:

    return "Argument should be a string: "+ str(e)

print is_isogram("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works, passed all hidden tests too. You are welcome

```
def is_isogram(word):
    '''This function tests for isogram'''
    word_set = set(word)

    if word.strip() == "":
        return (word, False)

    elif len(word) == len(word_set):
        return (word, True)

    elif type(word)!= str :
        raise TypeError

    else:
        return (word, False)
```

Comment: The OP is taking a test; answering it for him defeats the purpose. Helping is telling how he went wrong, not presenting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_isogram(word):
    return (word,True) if word and len(set(word)) == len(word) else (word,False)
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Please consider adding an explanation too, so that future users can understand this better.